# Nuxt Proxy changes POST to GET when proxy is set to true

Tags: proxy, axios, nuxt.js

In my universal nuxt app, I have setted proxy at true and rewritte my url to avoid CORS issue.
But when I'm setting proxy to true, all my post requests are changed to get request. Don't understand why and how to configure it no to have this transformation.

Here is my nuxt.config.js :

```
 /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  */
  axios: {
    proxy: true
  },
  proxy: {
    '/apicore/': { target: 'http://blablabla.fr', pathRewrite: { '^/apicore/': '' }, changeOrigin: true }
  }
```

My call:

```js
  async createJoueur({ state, dispatch, commit }, data) {
    const URL = '/apicore/joueur'
    await this.$axios
      .post(
        URL,
        data, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
          console.log('JOUEUR LOGGED : ')
          if (response.status === 200) {
          } else {
            console.log('Login failed / Not found')
          }
        }
      )
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('ERROR')
      })
```

With this proxy set to true, my post-call becomes a get one.
Do I have forgotten something in my configuration?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you find a solution by any chance ? I'm running into the same issue...

Comment: Same issue and wondering how this could be solved... @Bruno answer didn't solve for me

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same problem! i solved it using changeOrigin: false.

I know that it must be the default value ([Look at changeOrigin session](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) ),

but it seems like in nuxtjs proxy implementation this value default is true ([Look at Options session](https://github.com/nuxt-community/proxy-module)) .

Comment: `changeOrigin` doesn't seem to affect the HTTP method, I think your problem was a different one. See option description: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after some logging using the `onProxyReq` [option](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) I found out that the issue was the Cloudflare proxy, not the nuxt proxy. Cloudflare was forwarding HTTPS requests to HTTP and this [forces](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cloudflare-proxy-changing-post-to-get/158901) POST requests to become GET requests as is common with 301/302 redirects.

As far as I know, it's not possible to configure Cloudflare to do 308 redirects, which would not alter the HTTP method/body.